# Windows shows language switching menu when holding ALT

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, language, input-languages, overlay

Whenever I hold `Alt` and click `Shift` to change my input language from English to Hebrew and vica versa, it always shows the input selection menu in the middle left border of my screen like an overlay. As shown in this screenshot.

[image]

This issue started happening to me when I updated my windows to build 1903.

Is this a known bug? is there a fix for it or just wait for a new cumulative update?

Comment: I experienced it once or twice and it went away with next restart. So I thought it is a bug. In your case, does this happen also immediately after the restart?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, didn't receive notice the notification on my email.. This does happen also after restart.